DataTables 1.10 - column width is not working as expected
I have defined a datatable per the below.  I am using bootstrap 5.  I have read this thread but I still cannot get column width to work.  I have tried to change the width using 5%, 500%, 100%, 5px, 500px, 5000px and nothing will change the columnDef.
One guess is that the parent html made be overriding the datatables.   I am at a loss as to how to proceed so any help much appreciated.
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#post_index').DataTable({
        autoWidth:      false,
        stateSave:      true,
        stateDuration:  60 * 60 * 48, // save the state for 2 days.
        responsive:     true,
        pageLength:     10,
        lengthChange:   false,
        searching:      true,
        ordering:       true,
        "columnDefs": [
            { 
                "width": "5", 
                "targets": 0,
            },
            {
                "targets": 'nosort',  //Disable ordering on columns which have a class of 'nosort'
                "orderable": false
            }
        ],
  
    });
})();


You need to use a valid CSS selector - so "5" is not valid. But you mention that you have also tried other values (at least some of which are valid CSS selectors). So, "how to proceed...?" I cannot recreate your problem using your code (with a valid CSS selector). Therefore we need a [mre]. You can use a stack snippet to create a runnable demo in your question.

Or, start with a simple web page using only the code in your question, plus a simple HTML table (so, no Bootstrap, for example). That should work as expected (it works for me). Then add more features, step-by-step, making the demo more like your actual code, until you see the problem happening. Then you will have a much better idea of what is causing the problem.

Also, make sure you are using Bootstrap 5 in the correct way to integrate with DataTables.
